# PDO statements with named parameters VS question mark parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class for database management, and one of my sub-classes (the one that defines a query) is defined like this (just a sample, many other functions are actually stripped for testing purposes):

```
namespace Tests\SQL\Arguments {
    // SQL query
    class Query {
        public $attributes;

        // constructor for this object
        public function __construct() {
            if ($arguments = func_get_args()) {
                $this->attributes["query"] = current($arguments);

                if (sizeof($arguments) > 1) {
                    $this->attributes["parameters"] = array_slice($arguments, 1, sizeof($arguments));
                }

                return $this;
            }
        }
    }

    $query = new Query("INSERT INTO `clients/history` (`date`,`client`,`ammount`,`status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 57, 17852.25, "A");
    print_r($query);
}
```

As you can see, I automatically pick up the function arguments, so I can separate the query from its paremeters with ease at construction time. Apart from bulk `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` actions, I would like to provide some security, like preventing SQL injections and other things.

My question is... given this structure, when I pass this structure like (*just a simple example, it will be run in a different way, but this one is valid for the time being*):

```
$this->queries["clients/history"]->execute($this->attributes["query"], $this->attributes["parameters"]);
```

Will there be any different in using named parameters like `(:date,:client,:ammount,:status)` or using question mark parameters like `(?,?,?,?)`?

**EDIT - Better explanation**

Sorry for the (apparent) obscureness my question poses. My intention is to have a mechanism similar to sprintf but, instead of storing a string with all parameters composed into it, I just store the query and the parameters in a separate fashion.

This is just the Query class. There's also the QueryGroup class (for storing queries in groups), the Manager class (which stores and manages all database connections) and the Connection class (which is responsible for holding together all queries and query groups for a given database connection.

About the named parameters, I see no problem with the method I'm using, as this works, like I said, like the `sprintf` function. I'll be providing either question marks or the parameters' names in the query string.

I want to make a separation to provide addition filtering capabilities like escaping or quoting parameters to prevent some forms of injection or sabotage against a given database.

The `execute()` method I've exposed is just a paper-copy of PDO's `execute()` method. What I try to determine is if it's equally 'safe' to use named parameters or question mark parameters (or maybe there's some differences I'm not seeing there).

Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When you pick up the values from `func_get_args()` like above (this ain't your `execute` method), then they will be enumerated (hence unnamed) anyway.

Comment: Just curious. Do you have a solution for a query like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN(?)`?

Comment: I haven't implemented a proper solution yet, but I could perform an aditional pass with something like `array_map(function($input) { if (is_array($input)) { return explode("", $input) }}, $arguments)` or a similar procedure. Would have to test it, tough.

Comment: I see, a magic. Well, no more objections, I just prefer more robust way. Nevertheless, this `return explode` looks quite dangerous.

Comment: It was just a simple example coming out of my mind. The proper way would be to analyze each array/parameter member to stripe it out of any dangerous components like unwanted tags or intentional quotes to sabotage SQL statements, for example.

For now, I'm just doing simple testing on separate parts of the SQL classes. But thanks for hinting it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between named an unamed parameters is that with unnamed parameters you'll have to take care about the order in which they will be bound to the query.

Especially in your example unnamed params will fit very good as it eases the function call.

---

Further note that you won't need to call `return $this;` in a constructor method.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: You are welcome. Also check my update about `return $this;` in constructor.

Comment: About the 'no need to do `return $this`' phrase... yes. It's useful to have it as it allows me to do method chaining. That way, you can do something like `$query = (new Query(...))->output();` or, in the QueryGroup class, do something like `$group1->addQuery(...)->addQuery(...)->addQuery(...)->addQuery(...);` :P

Comment: This is new to me. (and did not work, using php 5.3.10) Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.4.13, always keeping up-to-date versions

Comment: Wow! I always wanted to have this feature. But can you try it without the return statement? It should work too. (I assume) , I would like to know exactly. Sidenote: When using Linux your are mostly bound to the PHP version your distribution provides. I'm on Ubuntu, it's currently 5.3.10

Comment: with named param you cannot use the same bound param multiple times as well

Comment: @hek2mgl No, it wouldn't work, as you need to return the object itself to be able to call another method on it. That's where the magic lies :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense correct, although the method chaining isn't intended for that (in this case, at least). It was just a general example about method chaining :P

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've executed this using PHP 5.3.10 cli and I'm pretty sure that is will work with other versions of PHP as well. What do you mean with *emulation mode*?

Comment: $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

Comment: @YourCommonSense This was new to me and should being mentioned. thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no technical difference (as PDO will just replace named placeholders to question marks internally), there is a usability issue

For the sprintf-like function question marks seems a lot better solution. As they will let you to use indeed sprintf-style (dunno why you're creating a whole class for the query):

```
$query = new Query("SELECT * FROM t WHERE a=? AND b=?", $ida, $idb);
```

while with named it will be a lot more verbose

Comment: A dedicated Query class is useful to me for a number of reasons like: 1) it allows me to separate in a logical fashion all query components; 2) it allows me to perform additional filtering/transforms to either the query or the parameters using a regex, a defined function, a lambda or any method, and 3) it will allow me (once I get it working) to dynamically calculate its string lenght on bulk operations so I can make it adjust for maximum performance regardless of the database driver I'm using :P

Comment: Looks like a query builder. I'd like to see it in action. To me most problems it's intended to solve are quite rare and occasional ones.

Comment: It's part of a framework I'm building. You're right about it... most problems could be occasional ones, although I'm designing the SQL class based on real-world scenarios I find at work with clients on different areas like eCommerce, CRM and billing management where known solutions don't/won't solve those problems (and they would gain a lot by doing it).